# Change background-color of component depending on where i call it

Tags: css, reactjs, state

I've got a problem I can't seem to solve.

I use a component several times in my app but I'd like the background to be different.

I've declared an empty state for the moment, which I'm using in background-color but I can't define the color the component will have. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help

Here is a little piece of my code :

```
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeGal: [],
      width: 1920,
      teamGal: {},
      isOpen: false,
      photoIndex: 0,
      bgColor: ''
    }
}

render() {
    const {activeGal, width, teamGal, isOpen, photoIndex, bgColor} = this.state

.gallery {
            background-color: ${bgColor};
            padding-bottom: 55px;
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest (and not recommended) way is to use the [`style` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style):

```
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { backgroundColor } = this.props;
    return <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor }} />;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "50vh", width: "50vw" }}>
      <Gallery backgroundColor="blue" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit nifty-hopper-n719w]

More popular solutions are using CSS-in-JS (like [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com/)) or [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) ([See CSS Variables for React Devs](https://joshwcomeau.com/css/css-variables-for-react-devs/)).